# Compilator won't stop printing the same, wrong answer

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

So I'm supposed to do a one line matrix from a document but the compilator keeps printing wrong answer. Not to mention when replacing one element with the other, the program won't react to the command.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

const char FV[] = "Masyvas.txt";
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int A[10];
    int i,j, m, n;
    ifstream Mas(FV);
    cout << "Parasykite masyvo elemento indekso numeri, pries kuri iterpsite nauja elementa - ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "irasykite iterpiamo elemento reiksme - ";
    cin >> m;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Mas >> A[i];
    }
    for ( j = n; j < 5; j++)
    {
        A[j + 1] = A[j];
        A[n] = m;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i)
    {
        cout << " " << A[i] << endl;
    }
    Mas.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "copilator", "compilator" – if you can't even spell the name of the tool that you are using correctly, how much effort I should assume you have put into researching the problem?

Comment: What input do you give the program? What is the actual output for that input? What is the expected output? What is the contents of the file you read?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i)
```

Here you have infinite loop, because condition `i < 5` is always true.

It was easy to find it on your side! Use any debugger next time to analyze so simple problems.

So, just replace that line by this line to fix it:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```